# How to imitate the browser to find & count text

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to count words which their visibility are visible in browser.
I'm using Scrapy to get link and parse theme with Selector.

Problem is I can only count all texts in spite of their visibility (hidden, in menu, in blockquote...) and the searching sites is a list of url (not the same structure)

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: This sounds like something you would need window.getComputedStyle for, so selenium or else switch to js.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy just give you the page source(ctrl+u) to get the rendered page you have to use the Selenium  or splash my splash is little speed compare to the Selenium but Selenium give you full control

Comment: Thanks, I've tried with scrapy slpash, It works well with the counter unless some problem with splash docker (it stopped when execute my list urls)